# Dotnetnuke homepage name included in url for some languages

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I'm having trouble with dotnetnuke 7. For some languages, when i enter my home page i have something like this (which is OK):

```
http://192.168.104.170/dotnetnuke/en-us/
http://192.168.104.170/dotnetnuke/de-de/
http://192.168.104.170/dotnetnuke/es-es/
```

but for some other languages i have my homepage name included in URL:

```
http://192.168.104.170/dotnetnuke/cs-CZ/homepagename
http://192.168.104.170/dotnetnuke/pl-PL/homepagename
```

It depends on user language - if the language is en-us, the proper url will appear.
But when he has pl-pl for example, he will be redirected to homepage with it's name included in URL.

How is that possible?
Where are some settings for this behaviour?
How to change website settings to **not** display home page name in url?

Comment: You might need to double check that Site Settings for each of the languages to see if the Home page is set for each of them.

Comment: I didn't realize that for different languages ther are different site settings... Thank you. Your comment should be marked as answer!

Comment: I wasn't quite sure that was it, but glad to hear it is. Answer added ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the Site Settings for each of the Languages, you likely need to check the Home page setting for each language.